# Echo Row Count() giving an error of `undefined function fetch_assoc()`

Tags: php

Please take a look on the below code, i can't be sure of what i m missing..

```
<?php
$sql4 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as rowCount FROM merchassignmenthistory WHERE executive = '$executive' ";
$result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
$rowCount= $result4>fetch_assoc();                                   
?>


<span><?php echo $rowCount['rowCount']; ?></span>
```

Now when i execute, it shows an error of `Call to undefined function fetch_assoc()`

Please note that, i have a session, and table in database set already ..
Any Help is Appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `-` in

```
$result4>fetch_assoc();
```

Should be:

```
$result4->fetch_assoc();
```